# Redirect binary output from file output to stdout

Tags: bash

I have a proprietary binary which stubbornly accepts two files as argument, first as input and second as output. I would like to

1. build the first argument w/o creating a temporary file
2. make binary write to stdout instead of a output file (second argument)

I solved the first issue with `<(...)` but not sure about the second argument.

I wrote a following script which looks like does everything as expected:

```
FILE1=$1
FILE2=$2

# checking that the files exist and other stuff

mkfifo myfifo

ThatBinary <( ... ) myfifo &

cat myfifo
```

The first argument for the binary is a combined Bash command which builds the first ``file''. The second argument is the named pipe to which the binary must write. All this is sent to background since writing to fifo blocks. Finally I print the named pipe's output to the stdout, as desired.

Is it possible to improve this command? Any hidden caveats? I am working with very large files (hundreds of thousands of text lines) and would love to be sure I miss nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ThatBinary <(...) /dev/stdout
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I can't redirect stdout of the script to a file. The error message read ``IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/dev/stdout' ''