# Redirect output from file to stdout

Tags: bash, shell, unix, stdout

I have a program that can output its results only to files, with `-o` option. This time I need to output it to console, i.e. `stdout`. Here is my first try:

```
myprog -o /dev/stdout input_file
```

But it says:

> /dev/ not writable

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387419/redirect-binary-output-from-file-output-to-stdout) that's similar to mine, but `/dev/stdout` is obviously not going to work without some additional magic.

Q: How to redirect output from file to `stdout`?

P.S. Conventional methods without any specialized software are preferable.

Comment: Can you show us sources of your program, where you doing the output?

Comment: @Samuel, I didn't write the program. It's `texi2html` actually, I guess its source code is available, but I doubt that there is a bug there.

Comment: @anubhava, thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `-o` switch entirely?

Comment: @TomFenech, output goes to file whose name is produced by replacing of `.texi` extension with `.html` extension. It just tries to guess name of the output file.

Comment: You can try `myprog -o - input_file`. Often a `-` is interpreted as stdin/stdout, but this depends on the program and is not part of the shell.

Comment: @RamboRamon, please add it as an answer, for it solves my problem!

Comment: Try `myprog -o /dev/tty input_file`

Comment: @Samuel, the same, /dev/ is not writable.

Comment: Looks like permissions issue. Try running with `sudo`

Comment: @Samuel, this operation does not require privileges of root by definition. I mean, even ordinary user should be able to redirect output to screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many tools interpret a `-` as stdin/stdout depending on the context of its usage. Though, this is not part of the shell and therefore depends on the program used.

In your case the following could solve your problem:

```
myprog -o - input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

If the program can only write to a file, then you could use a named pipe:

```
pipename=/tmp/mypipe.$$
mkfifo "$pipename"

./myprog -o "$pipename" &

while read line
do
    echo "output from myprog: $line"
done < "$pipename"

rm "$pipename"
```

First we create the pipe, we put it into `/tmp` to keep it out of the way of backup programs.  The `$$` is our PID, and makes the name unique at runtime.

We run the program in background, and it should block trying to write to the pipe.  Some programs use a technique called "memory mapping" in which case this will fail, because a pipe cannot be memory mapped (a good program would check for this).

Then we read the pipe in the script as we would any other file.

Finally we delete the pipe.

Comment: @Rambo Ramon:  I should point out that I did not see your comment on scottgwald's post until after I posted this.  I was testing the code when your wrote it!

Comment: No problem. It is nice to have a complete answer using named pipes, since it is more general than my answer. Take my upvote :)

Comment: This can fail for at least two reasons. First, if `myprog` removes the destination file before opening it; actually this seems to be the case, since `-o /dev/stdout` returns error `/dev/ not writable`.  And second, if `myprog` needs to `lseek()` through the output file; this is not very common, but it definitely can happen.

Comment: @lcd047: agreed.  Fundamentally we really need to know a lot more about the program.   If `lseek()` was being used then the accepted answer would not work (same with with `mmap()`), but it could be just going down a different branch if the output file is `-`.  Surprised that is not in the program's documentation. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can `cat` the contents of the file written by `myprog`.

`myprog -o tmpfile input_file && cat tmpfile`

This would have the described effect -- allowing you to pipe the output of `myprog` to some subsequent command -- although it is a different approach than you had envisioned.

In the circumstance that the output of `myprog` (perhaps more aptly `notmyprog`) is too big to write to disk, this approach would not be good.

A solution that cleans up the temp file in the same line and still pipes the contents out at the end would be this

`` myprog -o tmpfile input_file && contents=`cat tmpfile` && rm tmpfile && echo "$contents" ``

Which stores the contents of the file in a variable so that it may be accessed after deleting the file. Note the quotes in the argument of the `echo` command. These are important to preserve newlines in the file contents.

Comment: This may work as a sort of hack. This is definitely way to go if redirection is impossible, but I should note that it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how one would go about arguing about the details of the semantics of "redirection," but I do think this answers the question. If you put it in a black box you get a command that pipes the output of  `myprog` to `stdout` -- the fact that there's an intermediate file write doesn't matter in most normal circumstances.

Comment: To consider it an answer you should at least provide the code for deleting the temporary file afterwards. In addition to that I would propose to use a named pipe instead of a normal file.

Comment: @RamboRamon the solution does create the temporary file, just as written. You're correct that it doesn't remove it, that could be done with `&& rm tmpfile` at the end. I suppose it doesn't hurt to clean up, I'll add that.

Comment: @scottgwald re "doesn't matter in most normal circumstances" , without having any idea what `myprog` does, we don't know what's normal. Eg: If the whole point is that the output is too big for a file on disk, and we're redirecting so it can be consumed as it's written, temp file is useless.

Comment: @ckhan point taken. The answer by cdarke may actually do the trick, I was not familiar with named pipes.

Comment: In your defence, if the program used memory mapped files then this is the only solution so far posted here that would work.  Obviously it cannot be using `mmap` in this case because the accepted answer would not work either (creating and writing whole files using `mmap` is tricky anyway).

Comment: @RamboRamon just following up on my previous comment -- you'd have to do the `rm tmpfile` after whatever subsequent command -- if you put it right after the `cat` it doesn't have the desired effect. There may be an elegant way around this, but I haven't discovered it yet.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. Consider `dd if=/dev/random of=tmp.txt bs=2K count=1 &>/dev/null && cat tmp.txt | tr -cd '[[:alnum:]]._-'; rm tmp.txt`. It prints to `tmp.txt`, `cat` it, and does something with the output. In the end the `tmp.txt` is deleted.
Edit: I see now. Your problem is that you want to sell your solution as a black box. At first thought I do not have a solution as well.

Comment: @RamboRamon yes, your latter interpretation is correct. I think I just figured it out. The contents of the file can be stored in a variable: ``myprog -o tmpfile input_file && contents=`cat tmpfile` && rm tmpfile && echo $contents``